# Replace each leading tab by four spaces, recursively for every file

Tags: regex, sed, indentation

What is the *easiest* way of achieving this using common tools in Linux?

I have looked at:

1. `sed`, but don't know enough about how to count the matched leading tabs in an expression like `sed -i 's/^[\t]*/<what-to-put-here?>/g myFile.c`.
2. `astyle`, but can't figure out how to tell it to just reindent and NOT format
3. `indent`, same problem as astyle
4. `expand`, but it also replaces non-leading tabs and I have to handle the inplace replacement myself which is error prone.

I was just looking for a quick and easy solution that I can plug into a `find -type f -name "*.c" -exec '<tabs-to-spaces-cmd> {}' \;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri ':a;s/^( *)\t/\1    /;ta' file
```

Comment: Does this work in a recursive fashion as the question requested?

Comment: In case you are still anxiously worrying about the answer to your comment after 5 years. Yes it replaces all the tabs at the beginning of the line. I would say that it is iterative and not recursive, since sed doesn't have functions.

Comment: the regex `^( *)\t` will start at the beginning of the line `^` skip leading spaces and put them in a capturing group `( *)` and then a tab `\t`. The snippet matched by the regex will be replaced with `\1    `. This is the first capturing group `\1`, in other words the leading spaces (plus some spaces to replace the tab). `s` is the substitute command, so `s/^( *)\t/\1    /` replaces the first tab. `:a; ... ;ta` ensures that the regex is repeated as long as the substitution makes any changes. `:a` defines label `a` and `ta` is a conditional jump to label a, which is only executed on changes.

Answer (score 5):

You should really use `expand` since it is developed only to do that. From its [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expand):

> ```
> -i, --initial
>    do not convert tabs after non blanks
> ```

So the command for a single file would be:

```
expand -i -t 4 input > output
```

In order to use it with multiple file you will need a trick:

```
expand_f () {
  expand -i -t 4 "$1" > "$1.tmp"
  mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
}

export -f expand_f
find -type f -iname '*.c' -exec bash -c 'expand_f {}' \;
```

This is used to prevent `expand` to write on the file while it is still processing it, and to avoid redirecting the stdout of `find` instead of the one of `expand`.

Comment: Cool! Unfortunately I have to handle the temporary file creation and replacing the original file, which makes me feel uneasy :P

This seems to work though: ``find $vTargetDir -type f -exec sh -c 'tFile=`mktemp`; expand --initial --tabs=4 {} >$tFile && mv $tFile {};' \;``

Comment: @AlinTomescu Sure it works, it uses the same principle I used there. I'm glad I helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a single comand line, you can use `expand -i` like another answer describes, but to automate the process with the find command you can use:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'expand -i -t 4 {} > {}-t && mv {}-t {}' ';'
```

The reason you use the `cmd file > file-t && mv file-t file` trick is because the shell will erase the content of `file-t` upon seeing the redirection.  So if you had used `cmd file > file`, then `cmd` would have only seen an empty file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the redirection side-effect... That's why I don't like `expand` that much. The problem with this solution is that you lose file permissions when you replace the original file too.

Comment: Beware! this broke png images when I used it